# PHP - timezone_name_from_abbr showing wrong timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

For an online community I am building in PHP, I need to set the default timezone to the timezone of the user. This is the code I have now which returns the timezone offset of the user based on some JS:

```
$timezone = $_SESSION['time'];
$timezone_offset = filter_var($timezone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

The script puts the timezone offset in a session and this session is then assigned to the $timezone variable. When I echo $timezone, I get 'GMT 2', which is correct, so I made sure I only got the number 2 to use in the following code to get and set the timezone:

```
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset*3600, false);
date_default_timezone_set($timezoneName);
```

While the $timezone variable shows the correct timezone offset for my location: GMT +2 (I'm in Brussels, Belgium), I still get the wrong timezone when I echo my default timezone with `date_default_timezone_get()`, i.e. Europe/Helsinki, which has an offset of GMT +3, instead of GMT +2.

Does anyone know what could cause this and how I can fix it so it shows the correct timezone, Europe/Brussels or Europe/Paris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“GMT +2” is not *exactly* the Timezone for “Europe/Brussels”: it is the *actual* Timezone, due to Daylight Saving Time. The standard Timezone for “Europe/Brussels” is “GMT +1”.

So, to obtain right dates, you have to set `$_SESSION['time']` to “GMT +1” or to “CET” (Central Europe Time): by this way, you will have the right time during the whole year.

However, the best way is to specify directly “Europe/Brussels”, because DST settings can change for each country (actually, CET DST rules are deliberated by EU).